# WCF MetaData not working

Tags: wcf

I have tried several times to have my WCF service expose MetaData. Instead, I keep keeping the exception:

> The contract name 'IMetadataExchange'
>   could not be found in the list of
>   contracts implemented by the service
>   **SecurityBroker**.  Add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to the
>   configuration file or to the
>   ServiceHost directly to enable support
>   for this contract.

... when manually browsing to the service using IE.

(I am presuming this is the same reason why my client application isn't able to generate a service reference. Baby steps and all)

And yet my web.config looks okay:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpEnablingBehaviour">
            <webHttp />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpEnablingBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
    <service name="IWW.MIGTurbo2.WCF.Security.SecurityBroker">
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="default"
            contract="IWW.MIGTurbo2.WCF.Security.ISecurityBroker"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEnablingBehaviour">
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>
<client />
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="default" />
    </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

So I have my **IMetadataExchange** contract defined with **mex** fine, and hooked up, as far as I can see. Have I missed something daft?

**Edit**

My Service definition is shown below, if this is useful:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="IWW.MIGTurbo2.WCF.Security.SecurityBroker" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"   %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your config file has the behaviorConfiguration attribute on the "endpoint" element, but you also need it on the "service" element.

Answer (score 2):

I am using NetTcpBinding for all. In my case I was having the same issue and resolved it by adding:

(a) a behaviorConfiguration=""  to the mex endpoint

```
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" behaviourConfiguration="" />
```

(b) a behaviorConfiguration="mex" to the service definition:

```
  <services>
     <service name="AcmeService" behaviorConfiguration="mex">
```

(c) The behaviour entry

```
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behaviour name="mex">
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Comment: This helped me so i have upvoted, but please correct your ansewer to say includeExceptionDetailInFaults intead of includeExceptionDetailInFauls